# Wire Two 12v Batteries Together in Parallel With Solar Panel and Raspberry Pi

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, parallel

Please excuse my circuit below.  I am a high school robotics teacher, self taught in electronics, so I may have used some incorrect symbols and configurations.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that has a custom Pi Hat controlling a 12V solenoid.  The system seems to draw about 4W so I am trying to expand my battery from one to two 12V 18Ah cells in order to keep both of the SLA batteries charged above 80%.  Initial testing with one drew the charge down to about 60% overnight which, it is my understanding, is not advisable.  My solution is to add another battery and wire in parallel.  I want to confirm that the design of this circuit will work.  The Charge controller connects to the solar panel and the battery separately.  The RPi is powered with a USB connection.  The Pi Hat passes the 12V to the solenoid to open it using a GPIO pin attached to a transistor.  This means that the solenoid is only using power for about 20 minutes a day.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAD1Ez.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does this setup look correct or are there any other considerations before I put this together?  Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The root of the problem here is that the pi is unsuitable to battery power.  It is based on a chip intended for use in mains powered TV set top boxes.  You probably want either a very low power microcontroller, or if you must have a more advanced embedded-linux type system, one with a heritage to the mobile realm, ie, a "tablet" chip which unlike the pi's always-on processor actually has low power suspend modes.

Comment: Another issue is relying on solar power to keep the batteries charged. One or two dark, rainy, days, or a winter snow collection, would leave two dead (unrechargeable) batteries.

Comment: This application actually runs a watering system operating in the summer.  We receive a very large amount of sunlight at our latitude during the summer and in our climate, even with cloudy days.  I am trying to calculate for that.  My initial calculations have been adjusted since testing it out.  I've considered a RPi zero which uses much less power but has reduced wifi range, too short for its location.  I could try without but would prefer to solve this with the wifi option.  As such, I am trying to get the Pi 3 to work first.  Have I wired the batteries correctly to increase capacity?

Comment: Your circuitry for two batteries is correct. 4W x 24h = 96 Wh. If this is to be 20% of battery capacity you need   96/0.2 = 480 Wh battery capacity for 24 hr operation. 12V x 18 Ah = 216 Wh so two = 532 Wh (nominal) so about right. If you have rainy/cloudy days with below enough input you will drop under 80% SOC - which is OK occasionally.

Comment: Where are you located? With say 6 sunshine hours (equivalent full sun) to get 480 Wh a day in 6 h you need 80 W input. That's non trivial but also very doable.
As a starting rule of thumb until you address specifica DOUBLE the PV capacity compared to what is used - so 160 W. If the charge controller is NOT MPPT you lose about 30% from a 12V nominal panel as these are 18Vmp. A 150 Wmp or 200 Wmp PV panel is a good starting point. | Here are solar etc conditions for Loveland - just down the pike :-) [Gaisma loveland](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/loveland-colorado.html)

Comment: The 6th chart shows sunshine hours/day average by month
Insolation, kWh/m²/day Jan to December. 2.03 2.87 4.06 5.09 5.87 6.34 6.28 5.50 4.56 3.43 2.37 1.88 - You get over 4 SSH/day March to September. Design for 4 hours if winter no needed. Ask if more input needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuitry for two batteries is correct.

Load: 4W x 24h = 96 Wh.
If this is to be 20% of battery capacity you need 96/0.2 = 480 Wh battery capacity for 24 hr operation.
12V x 18 Ah = 216 Wh
so two = 532 Wh (nominal) so about right.

If you have rainy/cloudy days with below enough input you will drop under 80% SOC - which is OK occasionally.

In Windsor With say 4 sunshine hours (equivalent full sun) to get 480 Wh a day in 4 h you need 120 W input. That's non trivial but also very doable.
As a starting rule of thumb until you address specifics use 1.5 to 2 x the PV capacity compared to what is used - so 180- 240 Watt PV panels.
If the charge controller is NOT MPPT you lose about 30% from a 12V nominal panel as these are 18 Vmp.
A say 200 Wmp PV panel is a good starting point.

Here are solar etc conditions for Loveland - just down the pike :-)
[Gaisma loveland](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/loveland-colorado.html)

The 6th chart shows sunshine hours/day average by month

[image]

You get over 4 SSH/day March to September. Design for 4 hours if winter no needed. Ask if more input needed.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  That is what I needed to know.